# JQuery coding for creating a modal dialog works in jsfiddle but not in a local html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a modal dialog that appears when hovered using jQuery. 
the following codes works perfectly and modal box appears in jsfiddle but it doesn't appear the same way after I migrated it to my local text editor. Could anyone please help me with this? I also included the URL to the jsfiddle version.  Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/

Here are the HTML and CSS parts:

```
<head>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<style  type="text/css">


   @import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 

  .container {
      margin: 40px;
     }


</style>        

</head>     


<body>

 <div class="container">

   <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with data-trigger</a>

   <a id="popoverOption" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title">Popup with option trigger</a>
  </div>
```

The following is the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready( function() {

   $('#popoverData').popover();
   $('#popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" });

    })

   </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Your fiddle loads `bootstrap.min.js`, I don't see that in the the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you forget about bootstrap scripts? Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. First time dealing with bootstrap.